# iOS how can I close popover with button

Tags: ios, popover

on iOS how can I close popover with button into the popover.I call the viewController into the popover  but I can't close popover does not dismiss.How can I do that Please help

Comment: By "popover," do you mean a UIAlertView?  And by button, do you mean a button on the UIAlertView, or on the parent View?

Comment: ı dont mean UIALertView.popover isa difference component .I have two view(view controller) from first view I open the popover.into the popover display second view.I define popover into the first . from second view I can't access to the popover.I put the button second view .I want to close popover from second view

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
- (void)dismissPopOver
{
    [self.popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popOver = nil;
}
```

And call that method when the button is pressed.

Comment: I have two view(view controller) from first view I open the popover.into the popover display second view.I define popover into the first . from second view I can't access to the popover.I put the button second view .I want to close popover from second view.

Comment: @niyazigarip then you can use the delegate pattern to close it from the other viewcontroller

Comment: how can I do that Im new in objective c

Answer (score 0):

I usually end up having to make buttons that act as toggles for changing the visibility of the popover. Here's how I've always wired them up. The the action for my button looks like:

```
- (void)popoverButtonTapped:(id)button
{
    if (self.popover != nil)
    {
        // If the popover is open, close it
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popover = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, open a new popover
        self.popover = ...;
        // This is important because you want to know if the popover was closed
        // by tapping outside it or some external event
        self.popover.delegate = self;
    } 
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    if (popoverController == self.popover)
    {
        // nil out our reference since the popover was dismissed
        self.popover = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a navigation controller & a bar button on top of it. Insert your second view controller in navigation controller. Add a bar button item and refer it's action to a method that will dismiss your popover controller within the first view controller. May be you can use the following code:

As you are creating UIPopoverController, i assume you have already added the `UIPopoverConterollerDelegate` inside the .h file of your first view controller.

Declare a `UIPopoverController *popover;` in the .h file of your first view controller.

write the following codes where you are creating the popover controller.

```
-(IBAction)createPopoverController
{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *dismissButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Dismiss" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(dismissButtonPressed:)];

    [secondViewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:dismissButton];

    UINavigationController* navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navC];
    popover.delegate = self;
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(secondViewController.view.frame.size.width, secondViewController.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:yourButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    [secondViewController release];
}

-(void)dismissButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

I hope it will help you. :)